# NOT Routing a specific address through a certain adapter

Tags: network, vpn

Ok, I have a bit of a tricky problem:

I need to connect to a VPN in order to access our company servers from remote locations. At the same time, for some obscure reasons which the technician could never entirely explain to me, the VoIP telephony won't work when I'm in the VPN.

The problem seems trivial on the face of it. Just create a static route to the VoIP server through the physical interface.

Now here comes the tricky part: Depending on where I am, I might be connected through Wifi or through the physical connection of a docking station. That means, not only the IP of my machine will change, but the network interfaces will change as well.

The only constant is the utun0 interface, which messes up the connection.

Is there a way to solve this? Sort of a way to tell the system, "Chose any suitable route, but not one using the utun0 interface"?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which is your VPN software, if any?

Comment: About [utun0](https://superuser.com/questions/914685/what-is-creating-the-utun0-network-interface-on-osx-what-is-for-what-is-it-exa) . Basically it is the Tunneling interface created for VPN. When using your company VPN you are connected as If you were inside company network (kind of) . So the network you can see if the same as when your were connected directly in this network. If internet is not seen on this network you will not be able to see internet except to use 2 different physical interfaces : for VPN and the second one for internet.

Comment: What you're looking for is something called "split tunneling".  If your company's VPN does not support/allow that, you are out-of-luck.

Comment: I'm on Cisco AnyConnect. @Marc why do you think this should not be possible? As long as I control the routing table, what would keep me from setting up the necessary routes manually?